# Comparing non nested models with AIC

Tags: r, mixed-model, aic, lme4-nlme, nested-models

Say we have to GLMMs

```
mod1 <- glmer(y ~ x + A + (1|g), data = dat)
mod2 <- glmer(y ~ x + B + (1|g), data = dat)
```

These models are not nested in the usual sense of:

```
a <- glmer(y ~ x + A + (1|g),     data = dat)
b <- glmer(y ~ x + A + B + (1|g), data = dat)
```

so we can't do `anova(mod1, mod2)` as we would with `anova(a ,b)`.

Can we use AIC to say which is the best model instead?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The AIC can be applied with non nested models. In fact, this is one of the most extended myths (misunderstandings?) about AIC. See:

- [Akaike Information Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#How_to_apply_AIC_in_practice)
- [AIC MYTHS AND MISUNDERSTANDINGS](https://sites.warnercnr.colostate.edu/kenburnham/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2016/08/AIC-Myths-and-Misunderstandings.pdf)

One thing you have to be careful about is to include all the normalising constants, since these are different for the different (non-nested) models:

See also:

- [Non-nested model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/non-nested-model-selection)
- [AIC for non-nested models: normalizing constant](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37666/aic-for-non-nested-models-normalizing-constant)

In the context of GLMM a more delicate question is how reliable is the AIC for comparing this sort of models (see also @BenBolker's). Other versions of the AIC are discussed and compared in the following paper:

- [On the behaviour of marginal and conditional AIC in linear mixed models](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/97/4/773.short)

Comment: note that the marginal vs. conditional AIC distinction is most important when trying to compare models that differ *in their sets of random effects*

Comment: @Chandelier & Ben Bolker thank you very much for both your answers. Do either of you happen to have a more formal reference for the argument for using AIC in this way?

Comment: @user1322296 I would suggest to go to the root, this is [Akaike's paper](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/MiscDocs/Akaike_1974.pdf). AIC is obtained as an estimator of the divergence between your model and the "true model". So, no nesting assumed, only some regularity conditions.

Comment: So is it valid to compare the AIC of lm1=x~A+B*C and lm2=x ~ D+B*C for example? Thanks

Comment: There appear to be non-nested models for which AIC usage is not appropriate. Here are two examples: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/371068/99274) and [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/369851/99274). Would you please provide some conditions under which non-nested model selection does work?

Comment: @Carl, regarding nestedness, you may refer to the answer and the comment by Chandelier above.

Comment: @RichardHardy I do not program in R, so that I cannot fathom the notation. What is A? Is it an RV or a parameter?

Comment: @Carl, What A are you referring to? I do not see any in my references.

Comment: @RichardHardy Not in your answer, in the R-code in the question.

Comment: @Carl, A is a regressor there. Regardless, I think the specific references I gave above should be sufficient to address your comment.

Answer (score 14):

For reference, a counterargument:  Brian Ripley states in ["Selecting amongst large classes of models"](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Eripley/Nelder80.pdf) pp. 6-7

> **Crucial assumptions**
> ...
> The models are nested (footnote: see the bottom of page 615 in the reprint of Akaike (1973)).
> – AIC is widely used when they are not

The relevant passage (also p. 204 of another reprint of Akaike), starts I think with the phrase "The problem of statistical model identification is often formulated as the problem of selection of $f(x|_k\theta$) ...") is not quite available [here](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9cXgBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA199&ots=mNkdOB6K1h&sig=YL7MyVnhca1rUgL6qDLLBd5Pgec#v=snippet&q=formulated&f=false); I'm looking for a PDF of the paper so I can quote the passage here ...

(I've quoted it below, although honestly at this point I can't see how it supports Ripley's point - it certainly discusses the derivation in the context of nested models but ... ???)

Ripley, B. D. 2004. “Selecting amongst Large Classes of Models.” In *Methods and Models in Statistics*, edited by N. Adams, M. Crowder, D. J Hand, and D. Stephens, 155–70. London, England: Imperial College Press.

Akaike, H. (1973) Information theory and an extension of the maximum
likelihood principle. In *Second International Symposium on Information Theory* (Eds B. N. Petrov and F. Cáski), pp. 267–281, Budapest. Akademiai Kaidó. Reprinted in *Breakthroughs in Statistics*
, eds Kotz,S. & Johnson, N. L. (1992), volume I, pp. 599–624. New York: Springer.

For reference, see also [this post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249448/use-of-akaike-information-criterion-with-nonnested-models).

---

[image: longish passage from Akaike et al 1973 pp. 204ff]

Answer (score 10):

It appears Akaike thought AIC was a useful tool for comparing non-nested models.

> "One important observation about AIC is that it is defined without specific reference to the true model [ f(x|kθ) ]. Thus, for any finite number of parametric models, we may always consider an extended model that will play the role of [ f(x|kθ) ] This suggests that AIC can be useful, at least in principle, for the comparison of models which are nonnested, i.e., the situation where the conventional log likelihood-ratio test is not applicable."

(Akaike 1985, pg. 399)

Akaike, Hirotugu. "Prediction and entropy." Selected Papers of Hirotugu Akaike. Springer, New York, NY, 1985. 387-410.