# Compare the goodness of fit between two GLMs that are NOT nested

Tags: generalized-linear-model

as far as I understand, AIC or BIC can be used to judge the goodness of fit between two GLMs, but they two has to be one nested inside the other. If I have two models that are not nested and based on different data, is there a way to compare the goodness of fit? TIA

Comment: If they are based on different datasets then how will you distinguish between differences due to different models and differences due to different data?

Comment: I agree with @mdewey 
It's hard to imagine a meaningful scenario where you would want to compare GOF of two models fit to different data.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate:   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116935/comparing-non-nested-models-with-aic

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to get the residuals from each model and compare them.  You could use a t-test but it's probably more useful to simply compare absolute values and then ask yourself if the improvement in fit is worth it.  This is not a formal test but it's still useful.

Various plots of the outputs can be useful; I've found it helpful to look at Tukey mean difference plots, QQ plots of the different residuals; box plots of residuals and so on.