# Can I compare non-nested models with AIC?

Tags: aic, model-comparison, nested-models

Is it formally correct to compare two separate models with different independent variables?

For instance in R a pseudo code would be something like:

`AIC( lm( y ~ X ) )`

vs.

`AIC( lm( y ~ W ) )`

(`X` and `W` cannot feature in the same model as for instance `lm( y ~ X*W )` )

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116935/comparing-non-nested-models-with-aic

Comment: That question is about using the AIC with different Y variables, this question is about using the AIC to compare models w/ different X variables. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: That seems like a winner, @RichardHardy.