# How to correctly select parametric distribution that best fits survival data?

Tags: r, distributions, survival, goodness-of-fit

In the code below I test several parametric distributions against the `lung` dataset from the `survival` package data for best fit.

My main question with respect to the below code is my use of `fitdist(lung$time, dist)`. Is this the correct usage of the `fitdist()` function from the `firstdistrplus` package? Where the only data input into the model is the "time" column?

During my research as I drafted this code I came across examples where only the "time" values are input into the `fitdist()` function and there are further notes that "*...the* `fitdistrplus::fitdist()` *function can handle censored data without explicitly specifying the censoring status. The function assumes that any value greater than the largest observed event time is right-censored...*" which doesn't make sense to me. The `lung` dataset has a "status" column where 1=censored, 2=dead. Why wouldn't this extra information be used?

I reviewed the package documentation for the `fitdist()` function and the example dataset used is `groundbeef$serving` which doesn't have the time and status elements of the `lung` dataset.

Alterenatively, if `fitdist()` ignores censoring status, should I be instead using another parametric distribution fitting function from another package?

Code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(survival)

# Create vector of parametric distributions to test
distList <- c("weibull", "exp", "gamma", "lnorm")

# Function fits each distribution and extracts AIC, BIC, log-likelihood values
fit_dist <- function(dist) {
  tmp <- fitdist(lung$time, dist)
  c(tmp$aic, tmp$bic, tmp$loglik)
}

# Apply above function to each distribution in the distList
results_list <- lapply(distList, fit_dist)

# Convert the above list of results to a data frame
results_df <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(results_list), nrow = 3)))
colnames(results_df) <- c("aic", "bic", "logLik")
rownames(results_df) <- distList

# Find the distribution with the lowest AIC, BIC, and logLik values
bestFitAIC <- rownames(results_df)[which.min(results_df$aic)]
bestFitBIC <- rownames(results_df)[which.min(results_df$bic)]
bestFitLogLik <- rownames(results_df)[which.max(results_df$logLik)]

# Print the results data frame and best fitting distributions
results_df
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using AIC:", bestFitAIC, "\n")
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using BIC:", bestFitBIC, "\n")
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using Log-Likelihood:", bestFitLogLik, "\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting a distribution to censored data is somewhat different from fitting to uncensored data. The likelihood calculation with a censored observation involves the survival function of the distribution, not the probability of the observed value. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/145164/28500) for an introduction to the likelihood contributions. In the package to which you refer, uncensored data are handled by the `fitdist()` function while censored data require the `fitdistcens()` function.

Although those functions might help with simple data sets, as I understand it they won't help much with finding the best underlying distribution for a regression model involving covariates and censored outcomes. For a wide class of such models you can evaluate whether the distribution of (censored) residuals matches the associated error distribution. [These course notes](https://grodri.github.io/survival/ParametricSurvival.pdf) show error distributions associated with several types of parametric survival models. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/505453/28500) provides a brief introduction to calculating residuals in parametric models. Chapters 18 and 19 of Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/parsurv.html) discuss parametric modeling of survival data in detail, with an extensively worked-through example.

Answer (score 0):

For now I will be using the `flexsurvreg()` function of the `flexsurv` package, for fitting parametric distributions to right-censored data such as the `lung` dataset from the `survival` package. Below is the current state of code for goodness-of-fit tests for several parametric distributions.

I highly recommend studying Chapters 18 and 19 of Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies recommended by EdM as well as https://grodri.github.io/survival/ParametricSurvival.pdf!

Code:

```
library(flexsurv)
library(survival)

data(lung)

# Create vector of parametric distributions to test
distList <- c("weibull", "exp", "gamma", "lnorm","llogis","gompertz")

# Function fits each distribution and extracts AIC, BIC, log-likelihood values
fit_dist <- function(dist) {
  tmp <- flexsurvreg(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung, dist = dist)
  c(AIC(tmp), BIC(tmp), as.numeric(logLik(tmp)))
}

# Apply above function to each distribution in the distList
results_list <- lapply(distList, fit_dist)

# Convert the above list of results to a data frame
results_df <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(results_list), nrow = 3)))
colnames(results_df) <- c("aic", "bic", "logLik")
rownames(results_df) <- distList

# Find the distribution with the lowest AIC, BIC, and logLik values
bestFitAIC <- rownames(results_df)[which.min(results_df$aic)]
bestFitBIC <- rownames(results_df)[which.min(results_df$bic)]
bestFitLogLik <- rownames(results_df)[which.max(results_df$logLik)]

# Print the results data frame and best fitting distributions
results_df
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using AIC:", bestFitAIC, "\n")
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using BIC:", bestFitBIC, "\n")
cat("\nBest fitting distribution using Log-Likelihood:", bestFitLogLik, "\n")
```